# How to package spring-boot to jar with local jar using maven

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar

I have a jar in my system, and I want to package it into jar application using maven, my dependency and plugin as below:

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wltea</groupId>
            <artifactId>IKAnalyzer</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/BOOT-INF/lib/IKAnalyzer3.2.3Stable.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>


    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>repackage</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <mainClass>gpdi.MyApp</mainClass>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I also try `maven-dependency-plugin` but did'nt work when packaging jar file.

```
   <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/BOOT-INF/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <includeScope>system</includeScope>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: What kind of behavior are you seeing? Does your project inherit from spring boot? https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-build-systems.html#using-boot-maven-parent-pom

Comment: @yngwietiger Yes, I am using spring-boot, can run the main class in IDEA, But I don't know how to package jar file which may run at server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the below plugin and clean your project :

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install-Transformation lib</id>
            <phase>clean</phase>
            <configuration>
                <file>${basedir}/file/path/jarname.jar</file>
                <repositoryLayout>default</repositoryLayout>
                <groupId>org.wltea</groupId>
                <artifactId>IKAnalyzer</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                <generatePom>true</generatePom>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-file</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Once you clean the project. Comment `scope` and `systempath` like below then build and install :

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wltea</groupId>
    <artifactId>IKAnalyzer</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.3</version>
    <!--scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/BOOT-INF/lib/IKAnalyzer3.2.3Stable.jar</systemPath-->
</dependency>
```

Comment: Is there a derect way to patching the "<scope>system</scope> jar" into my application? Because there are a few colleagues work together with me , and we don't have private maven repository and want to use git to share the "local jar" in the project. In this case, all of us must install the "local jar" ?

Comment: Installing this jar into the local repository helps